# What are the usual limits for web server to respond before browsers time out?

Tags: browser, timeout, webserver, connection-timeout

I thought the usual response time has to be something like 30 seconds or something like that, but I actually have a development website running on a Macbook using an MVC framework responding in 45 seconds and all the major browsers won't time out.  What is the usual rule of how long before the browsers will time out?

Comment: Are you referring to a connection timeout, a request timeout or a response timeout. Timeout is very broad.

Comment: It depends on whether each server your request calls is up along with its timeout setting and the web application session state timeout (20 mins for .Net / ISS).